# Add an empty option in select2 when options are created from jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I try to add an empty `<option></option>` when I set the options from `jQuery` but when the page is loaded the fist option is selected. I added `allowClear: true, placeholder: "Select...",` but it didn't worked.

I have found a walk around, to clear the option after I initialize the `select2`, which works but is there any better solution?

```
$(".select2-it").val(null).trigger('change');
```

```js
var itData = [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'Apps',
    children: [{
        id: '1',
        text: 'App1'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        text: 'App2'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        text: 'App3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'bug'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: 'duplicate'
  }
];

$(".select2-it").select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: "Select...",
  data: itData,
  width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="it-target" class="select2-it form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Why do you want to add an empty option?

Comment: The option is required in my form and I want the user to select a value and not take the first option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend the empty option in the DOM element (using [.prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)) before calling the Select2 initializer on your input.

```js
var itData = [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'Apps',
    children: [
        { id: '1', text: 'App1' },
        { id: '2', text: 'App2' },
        { id: '3', text: 'App3' }
    ]
}, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'bug'
}, {
    id: 5,
    text: 'duplicate'
}];

$(".select2-it").prepend('<option></option>').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Select...",
    data: itData,
    width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select id="it-target" class="select2-it form-control"></select>
```